# MudBlazor mini bar chart not available

Tags: blazor, bar-chart, mudblazor

I'm trying to recreate the mini bar chart shown on the home page of mudblazor.com
[image]

However, this is not a component in the documentation.
Anyone that knows how I could recreate this without any complex CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

If the default bar chart  [mudblazor.com/components/barchart](https://www.mudblazor.com/components/barchart) is not enough, have a look at [Plotly Blazor](https://github.com/LayTec-AG/Plotly.Blazor). You can use their [bar chart](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/). I find it very customisable.